# Часовые пояса

Tags: php, время

Задача такова:

Юзер из Китая добавил материал на сайт и время в БД занеслось его (китайское). Например, 15:40, а я, юзер из Москвы. И у меня время 20:40. Как сделать следующее:

Юзер из Китая должен видеть время добавления материала -  15:40, а я, из Москвы - 20:40.

Каков алгоритм осуществления?

Comment: Юзеры зарегистрированные или независимо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Писать в БД время сервера, а на клиенте это время изменять в зависимости от часового пояса юзера

Comment: не правильно вообще как-то писать время юзера. Путаница получится. Согласен с @Андрей Советкин, что лучше писать время сервера

Comment: поддерживаю, время юзверя писать вообще глупо)

Comment: А еще лучше - писать UTC....